# Forwarding Email of a future employer to my Supervisor. Broken code of confidentially?

Tags: email, privacy

I am applying for postdoc positions. A faculty member sent me an Email encouraging me to apply for his open position. He disclosed with me the name of two famous companies that are involved in his project. He also mentioned the name of a famous scientific problem he is currently working on, as a part of this project.

I forwarded his Email to my supervisor, asking for his advice on this position. Have I done something illegal, in terms of breaking the code of confidentially?

Comment: Why do you think there would be confidential information involved?

Comment: Because, the faculty has shared with me the name of companies he is working with. He has also shared with me the name of scientific problem he is currently working on.

Comment: Was the information you shared in the public domain already?

Comment: It is hard to imagine how a perspective employee could be required to keep names confidential.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but unless you signed a nondisclosure agreement or made some other legally binding promise not to disclose the information, you almost certainly didn't do anything illegal by forwarding the email. Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_disclaimer. Keep in mind that illegal and improper/unethical are two different things, so it's still quite possible that what you did will upset the sender of the email.

Comment: @Don Romik: What you explained completely makes sense, and brung me some relief!

Comment: In which country/state are you located? Laws differ between different jurisdictions. However, I agree with @Don Romik. His information applies to a majority of jurisdictions, and forwarding an email will not be considered any breach by a court, unless you did it with malicious intent, which then would fall upon faculty to proove, and they would simply loose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legally, no. Ethically, no. He felt free to reveal it to you, you felt free to reveal it to someone else. And nothing he revealed seems that earthshaking to me: Lots of people work on famous problems, lots of people work with major corporations.